# TypeScript type for AngularJS $routeParams?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Can you guys tell me why, when I code AngularJS with TypeScript in Visual Studio, I cant compile this code: ? am I using the right type **ng.route.IRouteParamsService** for **$routeParams** ???

var param = $routeParams.id wont compile, but its a valid way to write code.
If I dont declare type for $routeParams, there are no compiler complains and everything works. **Doesnt make much sense to me. Please advice.**

[image: List item]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a project with ngRoute typings in front of me, but have you tried `$routeParams['id']`?

The [angular-route typings show](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/4869992bc079b88280b9ff91213528904109e8ae/angular-route/index.d.ts) it's a string index'd object.

```
namespace route {
        interface IRouteParamsService {
            [key: string]: any;
        }
}
```

Since the typings can't know ahead of time what params you will have, this is the best way (without generics, which would be cumbersome in this case) to allow for dynamic objects.

Comment: Yes, the indexer works just fine. Its a little weird that accessing the parameter by name *$routeParams.id* works if I dont provide *ng.route.IRouteParamsService* type, if I remove type, I can use *$routeParams.id* directly

Comment: @monstro if you don't type `$routeParams` as `ng.route.IRouteParamsService` then your Typescript project is (probably, depends on `tsconfig.json`) treating it as type `any`. Since it's `any` it could have any form and Typescript lets you treat it as such.

Comment: yes, it seems this object is similar to dynamic ViewBag in MVC

Comment: @monstro Yup, very similar concept. Even in Angular 2 where the framework is designed in Typescript and takes advantage of generics / union types we still see this kind of dynamic container object, especially in the router.